# Knowing which method is throwing the exception

Tags: c#, exception

I'm reading information from an xml file and at some point an exception may be thrown by two `Boolean.Parse()` instructions

Given that the whole snippet is already under a try statement, I wanted to put all catches in one place instead of putting the two above method calls under some other try-catch.

My question is how can I know which method is throwing the exception? I have to display different error messages depending on who's failing to convert.

```
try
{
    XmlNode db = _xml.SelectSingleNode("root/database");


    string usr = db.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText;
    string psw = db.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
    string srvr = db.SelectSingleNode("server").InnerText;
    string dbn = db.SelectSingleNode("dbname").InnerText;

    //Here a FormatException can be thrown by both these Parse()
    //And I need to know which is the caller in order to display the correct error message
    bool clean_db = Boolean.Parse(db.Attributes["clean"].Value);
    bool functions = Boolean.Parse(db.Attributes["insertFunctions"].Value);


    return new DatabaseConfiguration(usr, psw, srvr, dbn, clean_db, functions);
}
catch (XPathException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("<database> node is missing");
}
catch(FormatException e)
{
    //Here I'm supposed to do something to get the caller
    Console.WriteLine("Error message");
}
```

Comment: You could use `Boolean.TryParse`, but then you'll get some `if` statements. It will enable you to throw a custom exception. Although this doesn't work if `db.Attributes["clean"] == null`.

Comment: I'm checking earlier whether they are null or not

Comment: Unfortunately, your use case requires additional structure so your desire not to have additional catches (or some other mechanism for failure detection as suggested by others), is not going to be able to be realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> The TryParse method is like the Parse method, except the TryParse method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails.

So you can simply check for failure with the returning Boolean value

```
 bool clean_db;
 if(!Boolean.TryParse(db.Attributes["clean"].Value),out clean_db)
 {
    // Failled 
 }

 bool functions;
 if(!Boolean.TryParse(Boolean.Parse(db.Attributes["insertFunctions"].Value,out functions)
 {
   // Failled
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Throw an additional try/catch around each of the boolean.parse methods, then have the catch just be:

```
try
{
    XmlNode db = _xml.SelectSingleNode("root/database");


    string usr = db.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText;
    string psw = db.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
    string srvr = db.SelectSingleNode("server").InnerText;
    string dbn = db.SelectSingleNode("dbname").InnerText;

    //Here a FormatException can be thrown by both these Parse()
    //And I need to know which is the caller in order to display the correct error message
    bool clean_db;

        try
        {
            clean_db = Boolean.Parse(db.Attributes["clean"].Value);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception ("clean exception");
        }

        bool functions;

        try
        {
            functions = Boolean.Parse(db.Attributes["insertFunctions"].Value);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception ("function exception");
        }

        return new DatabaseConfiguration(usr, psw, srvr, dbn, clean_db, functions);
    }
    catch (XPathException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<database> node is missing");
    }
    catch(FormatException e)
    {
        //Here I'm supposed to do something to get the caller
        Console.WriteLine("Error message");
    }
```

then the outer catch will tell which line the exception came from.

then modify your outer catch to show the exception message.

Here's how Steve suggested, since he told me to update my answer :)

```
try
{
    XmlNode db = _xml.SelectSingleNode("root/database");


    string usr = db.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText;
    string psw = db.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
    string srvr = db.SelectSingleNode("server").InnerText;
    string dbn = db.SelectSingleNode("dbname").InnerText;

    //Here a FormatException can be thrown by both these Parse()
    //And I need to know which is the caller in order to display the correct error message
    bool clean_db = ParseDbAttributeValue(db.Attributes["clean"].Value);

    bool functions = ParseDbAttributeValue(db.Attributes["insertFunctions"].Value);

    return new DatabaseConfiguration(usr, psw, srvr, dbn, clean_db, functions);
}
catch (XPathException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("<database> node is missing");
}
catch(FormatException e)
{
    //Here I'm supposed to do something to get the caller
    Console.WriteLine("Error message");
}

private bool ParseDbAttributeValue(object myValue)
{
    return Boolean.Parse(myValue);
}
```

Comment: I had already said that _Given that the whole snippet is already under a try statement, I wanted to put all catches in one place instead of putting the two above method calls under some other try-catch._

Comment: You can preserve the readability of the code by extracting this into a method call instead of having the nested try blocks.

Comment: @Phate01 then you'll probably just have to parse which line the exception came from, but that could change if you every make code changes

Comment: @Steve Mitcham that's right, I hadn't thought about it. Make an answer!

Comment: Since he's wrapping the Parse Exception with an outer exception with the correct error message, you don't need to worry about parsing stack traces.  You just use the exception message as written.

Comment: I'll just let ganders adjust his answer.